# How do I format an 'else' in to this code?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm learning to code, and I know this is probably a terribly easy question to answer, but I just can't figure out how to echo nothing when there is no data here.

I know it has to do with using 'else', but where do I put it? This code basically summons social media links and I want both to be dependant on not showing if there is no data. I think there has to be somewhere in the first paragraph that the else code is supposed to go, but I really don't know where.

```
<?php if($instance['display_desc']) : ?>
<?php $description = get_the_author_meta( 'description', $user_id ); ?>
<?php echo wpautop( $this->trim_chars( $description, $instance['limit_chars'] ) ); ?>

<?php $instagram = get_the_author_meta('instagram'); ?>
<?php $twitter = get_the_author_meta('twitter'); ?>

<?php echo
$authsocial .= "<a class=\"author-ig\" href=\"https://instagram.com/" . $instagram . "\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">@" . get_the_author_meta('instagram') . " </a>"
?>

<br />
<?php echo
"<a class=\"author-tw\" href=\"https://twitter.com/" . $twitter . "\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">@" . get_the_author_meta('twitter') . " </a>";
?>

<?php endif; ?>

--

Igor helped me loads, but I wonder why this isn't working:

if (!empty($instagram)): ?><br />
<a class="author-ig" href="https://instagram.com/<?php echo $instagram ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">@<?php echo get_the_author_meta('instagram'); ?></a>

if (!empty($twitter)): ?><br />
<a class="author-tw" href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo $twitter ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">@<?php echo get_the_author_meta('twitter'); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php else: ?>
ELSE_HTML_GOES_HERE
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: if there is nothing to do in the else, don't have it, you don't need an else statement to make the if run

Comment: What do you mean by "where"?

Comment: @treyBake
Right now the code still renders the links but without the $instagram or the $twitter tag. I'm wondering how to make it not render those two echos at all if there is no value in those.

Comment: oh - do an `empty()` check to see if the data is there, if it is echo,

Comment: If it still actual... You missed to add php open tag in lines where you have `if`. Just add a `<?php ` before your `if(!empty(`. And you closed your php code with `?>` somewhere before. That's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy! You can use

> `if(...) {...} else {...}`

or

> `if(...): else: ... endif;`

And I would not litter so much with  tag on every line. Readability goes down.

Your code reshape:

```
<?php
  if ($instance['display_desc']):
    $description = get_the_author_meta( 'description', $user_id );
    echo wpautop( $this->trim_chars( $description, $instance['limit_chars'] ) );

    $instagram = get_the_author_meta('instagram');
    $twitter = get_the_author_meta('twitter');

    echo $authsocial .= "<a class=\"author-ig\" href=\"https://instagram.com/" . $instagram . "\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">@" . get_the_author_meta('instagram') . " </a>";

  if (!empty($twitter)): ?><br />
  <a class="author-tw" href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo $twitter ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">@<?php echo get_the_author_meta('twitter'); ?></a>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
ELSE_HTML_GOES_HERE
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This almost has solved it, the only thing is that there's still an @ coming from the empty twitter tag in the scenario I'm working with. So that complete line needs to disappear, which it doesn't with your code.

Comment: Added check for empty $twitter var

Comment: Thank you so much Igor, you've been a great help. Have a nice day!